# know the library/binary modified as part of new package release

Tags: package-management, security, libraries, source-packages

How to know list of files/libraries/binary modified/updated in new release of package.?

Ex: i have package apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.19 and i have older version package apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17. how can i know which .so/binary/files has source code changes are made in new version of package.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

You can read "changelog" for `apt` with

```
apt changelog apt
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for the answer. i tried the command but command output not telling which .so library changed as part of new package version.